# Woocommerce language isn't default language

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, language

I have a multilingual website (french and occitan) with Woocommerce.
My default language (in settings - general) is french.
But Woocommerce is displayed in occitan (e.g. the "turn to shop" or "add to cart" buttons) even when I'm on a french page.
I have the french translation files in wp-content/languages/plugins.
I tried without being connected and it didn't work, so it isn't a user setting problem.
I can't understand why Woocommerce does'nt display in my website default language.
Any ideas ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: do you use polylang ?

Comment: Yes, I do. I just tried to set french as default language on Polylang and install Woocommerce again, but it didn't work.

Comment: Ok, when I desactive Polylang, my Woocommerce cart page is in french. But when Polylang is activated (even with french as default language), the cart page is in occitan.
Do I have to uninstall and reinstall everything ? I would like to avoid this, as I have to finish the website on thursday...
Please, someone has an idea to how to prevent polylang to change woocommerce default language ?
Thanks